# Can a WordPress site be rebuilt even if the database has been deleted?

Tags: wordpress

I have a problem with my WordPress website.

The database has been deleted and the site no longer works and requires me to rebuild it again. How can I retrieve a site?

Comment: without db backup you simply can't, you have to setup as new db. You can ask your hosting provider for the DB backup if they have/